# Split one row into multiple rows based on comma-separated string column

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table like below with columns `A(int)` and `B(string)`:

```
A   B
1   a,b,c
2   d,e
3   f,g,h
```

I want to create an output like below:

```
A    B
1    a
1    b
1    c
2    d
2    e
3    f
3    g
3    h
```

If it helps, I am doing this in Amazon Athena (which is based on presto). I know that presto gives a function to split a string into an array. From presto [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html):

> split(string, delimiter) → array
>   Splits string on delimiter
>   and returns an array.

Not sure how to proceed from here though.

Comment: Not an answer, but you should generally avoid storing CSV in your tables, for the very reason you are now seeing; it makes the data much harder to work with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `unnest` on the array returned by `split`.

```
SELECT a,split_b 
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(b,',')) AS t (split_b)
```

Comment: how is it ensured that 'a' is joined only with the values stored against it? Doesn't seem evident from the query. Is unnest treating column-A as pivot?

Comment: @ishan3243 see examples in the documentation https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest